# How to set environment variable in Yosemite for local ssh sessions

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm having a problem with Yosemite, it won't set the environment variables when doing:

```
ssh localhost
env | grep myvar
```

no sign of myvar.
I've managed to get Yosemite to set the environment variables for terminal sessions etc using the excellent suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite/26179907#26179907).

Why is it not working for the ssh session?

Comment: How are you setting mylar?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add your variable to your `.bash_profile`: `export MYVAR="Whatever"`

```
$ . .bash_profile
$ echo $MYVAR
Whatever
$ ssh localhost
Password:
Last login: Tue Nov 18 18:58:41 2014 from localhost
$ echo $MYVAR
Whatever
$
```